# set margin to menu item in navigation drawer but not header part

Tags: android, android-navigationview, material-components, material-components-android

I have NavigationDrawerActivity. I want to set left margin to menu items.

I tried like this.

```
<style name="NavigationDrawerStyle" parent="AppTheme">
   <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">@dimen/dimen20dp</item>
</style>
```

and applied this style to `NavigationView`.
Margin left is set to both header part and list.
I want it to apply to only list.

Comment: Use `listPreferredItemPaddingLeft` item in `NavigationDrawerStyle` and add your dimens there.

Answer (score 4):

Use **`app:itemIconPadding`** to change the margin between the icon and the text

```
<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
    app:itemIconPadding="xxdp"
    ..>
```

[image]

Use the **`app:itemHorizontalPadding`** to change the padding before the icon:

```
<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
    app:itemHorizontalPadding="0dp"
    />
```

[image]

Use **`app:itemShapeInsetStart`** to change the padding of the shape

```
<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
    app:itemShapeInsetStart="0dp"
    />
```

[image]

You can also use a custom style:

```
  <style name="CustomNavigationView" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.NavigationView">
       <item name="itemIconPadding">@dimen/.....</item>
       <item name="itemHorizontalPadding">@dimen/....</item>
       <item name="itemShapeInsetStart">@dimen/..../item>
  </style>
```